# How to hide a article(parent) tag if the p tag contains only "dots (....)"?

Tags: jquery

I need to hide a `article` (parent) tag if `p` tag contains dots(....) maybe upto several dots or even two dots. I used many code variation but I couldn't identify the dots. How it possible?

My code 1

```
        $(".rating_only .comment_outer").each(function(){
          if($(this).find("p:has(...)").length > 0){
            $(this).hide();
          }
        });
```

My code 2

```
            $(".rating_only .comment_outer").each(function(){
            if (!$(this).text().length > 3) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });​
```

My code 3

```
    $('.rating_only .comment_outer p').each(function() {

    var textOfPara = $(this).text();
    textOfPara.length;
    if(textOfPara=="...."  ) {
    (this).parents(".rating_only .comments-area article").hide();
    }
});
```

My Code 4

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var stringvar = $('.rating_only .comment_outer p').text();

        if ((stringvar.charAt(0) == ".") && (stringvar.charAt(2) == "."))
        {
            console.log ('hai' );

           (stringvar).parents(".rating_only .comments-area article").hide();
        }


    });
```

My Code 5

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($(".comment_outer p"),function(){
        if($(this).text().substring(1, 2) == ".."){ 
          $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

My Code 6

```
 $('.rating_only .comment_outer').each(function() {

     $(this).find(' p ').text().parents("article").hide();
```

});

I know that Code No.6 not relevant for this specific condition.

My HTML :

```
    <div class="comment_outer"> 
       <p>….. </p>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your valuable help.I tried as much I can but it didn't work.

Comment: i would do this with regex

Comment: What do you mean with p tag contains dots. Where is the html

Comment: @DOCASAREL HTML example code is at the end of question.

Comment: hi Pawel, Can you please try using Regular expression.Thanks

Comment: @DOC ASAREL . Its a comment review box. If somebody add a dots , I need to hide, Please check the last html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RegExp for that. Combining it with jQuery `.filter()` function, you get:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".comment_outer").filter(function() {
    var ok = false;
    $.each($("p", this), function() {
      if ($(this).text().match(/[^\.\s…]/)) {
        ok = true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    return !ok;
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment_outer">
  <p>Some text and some dots ...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>. . .</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="comment_outer">
  <p>…</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>. . .</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Justinas. This code is working.Thanks $(".rating_only").filter(function() { return $(this).find(".comment_outer p").text().match(/…|(\.{1,3})/).length; }).hide(); but it also hide if there has a text.I need to also show if that p tag contains text.Can you please help me?

Comment: I am wondering about the solution.Its not working. Code looks ok but still didn't hide article tag.Its a WordPress comment section. Thanks for your help

Comment: @KevinJohn paste your HTML to my Code Snippet and check than. I can't help you without code.

Comment: I added a line of html under the second <div class="comment_outer"> ". Now its not working. can you please check

Comment: @KevinJohn because you are adding NOT `.` three times, but `&hellip;` html code. Updated answer. Next time specify that it's not simple 3 dots, but `&hellip;` too.

Comment: oh.. got it..Thanks. It was the main issue . How to add these line into code your code?.

Comment: .Many Thanks your hard work. Its working well. you are awesome..Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have two different characters. The ellipsis character (…) and a period character(.), so you'll need to handle those separately:

```
$("article").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(".rating_only .comment_outer p").text().match(/…|(\.{2,3})/).length;
}).hide();
```

This will use regex to match if the text for the `.rating_only .comment_outer p` inside each article matches either one ellipsis character, or 2/3 sequential period characters. You could `trim()` the `text()` to take into account whitespace if you wanted:

```
$("article").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(".rating_only .comment_outer p").text().trim.match(/^…|(\.{2,3})$/).length;
}).hide();
```

Comment: @Regent That would mean iterating back up the DOM to find the parent article again. OP wishes to hide the `article`, not the `p` (I think!)

Comment: Hi Dear RGraham, Code is working .Thanks $(".rating_only").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(".comment_outer p").text().match(/…|(\.{1,3})/).length;
}).hide();   but it also hide if there has a text.I need to also show if that p tag contains text.Can you please help me?

Comment: @KevinJohn Use the second option :)